# To exclude Radio button to call Jquery Function on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, blur

In my Form I have Input fields as text, radio button and checkbox. I am binding function call on 'blur' of
input fields. But I want to exclude Radio button. So that on change of 'Radio button'  JS function should not get 
called.
My current code is mentioned below:

```
$('input, select').bind('blur', function () {
            var target = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                //some code here
            }, 200);
        });
```

How can I exclude Radio button from it.

Comment: `$('input, select').not(':radio')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `.not` the [radio selector](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

```
$('input, select').not("[type=radio]").on('blur', function () {
```

or

```
$('input, select').not(":radio").on('blur', function () {
```

The first is faster

Comment: Thanks mplungjan and Roger

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
$('input[type!="radio"], select').on('blur', function () {
            var target = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                //some code here
            }, 200);
});
```